# How to emit function with id from child component to parent in vue.js

Tags: vuejs2

I have a card component and a house component . I want to emit function along with id from child to parent component.I want to call edit function from card component which is in house component.
card.vue

```
  <tr class="registrationtable" v-for="valueList in values" v-bind:key="valueList">
              <td class="registrationtable" v-for="head in columnHeader" v-bind:key="head">
                <span v-if="href.includes(head)">
                  {{ head }}
                  <a
                    v-for="action in actionList"
                    v-bind:key="action"
                    v-on:click="methodToCall(valueList[head])"
                    >{{ action }}</a
                  ></span
                >

                <span v-else></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
```

```
  created() {
    this.methodToCall(id); 
  },
```

house.vue

```
<card :method-to-call="editFunction" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.$emit()`

card.vue template

```
<tr class="registrationtable" v-for="valueList in values" v-bind:key="valueList">
              <td class="registrationtable" v-for="head in columnHeader" v-bind:key="head">
                <span v-if="href.includes(head)">
                  {{ head }}
                  <a
                    v-for="action in actionList"
                    v-bind:key="action"
                    v-on:click="methodToCall(valueList[head])"
                    >{{ action }}</a
                  ></span
                >

                <span v-else></span>
              </td>
            </tr>
```

card.vue

```
methods:{
methodToCall:function(id){
     this.$emit('methodToCall', id)
}
}
```

house.vue

```
<card :method-to-call="editFunction" />
```